# Why does the C89 library not contain functions to create/delete/rename/remove a directory?

Tags: c

I apologize for my bad English.

Why does the C89 library not contain functions to create/delete/rename/remove a directory? Or maybe I didn't find that? I see functions for some file operations only, but not for directories.

Thank you
Best Regards

Comment: Perhaps, for the same reason they aren't in C99, to keep things small and simple?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Otherwise, `<dirent.h>` header file is now pseudo-standard: both MinGW and GCC have it. So, you can handle directories on a conventional personnal computer, without too much trouble.

Comment: MinGW is GCC. MSVC has something too. And so does Open Watcom and even ... Turbo C. :)

Answer (score 2):

Traditionally (and C89 is tradition) the directory structure is seen as part of the operating system, and at the time (1989) there were still OS arround that had incompatible concepts for that.

Nowadays, there would perhaps be enough common ground to integrate such a thing in C, as it is e.g now done for threading in C11, but I am not aware of an initiative to do so.

Comment: Is it means that on C is impossible to write a code, platform-independent which are working with directories?

Comment: C is still supposed to be usable on small devices without a directory structure, as well as big iron mainframes running z/OS. IBM wouldn't like a language standard to impose a file structure on the operating system. :-)